# How to improve OCR accuracy?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have 2 images like shown below. A.png is perfectly read by tesseract but B.png is terribly bad accuracy even though the B.png is similar to A.png. How can I improve the accuracy? I have no idea where to start debugging?

- A.png

[image]

- B.png

[image]

- Run OCR

```
# tesseract -v
tesseract 4.1.1-rc2-22-g08899
```

```
# tesseract A.png stdout -l jpn --psm 6
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
第 3 期 決算 公告 令 和 2 年 2 月 7 日
大 阪 市 中 央 区 南 新町 一 丁目 3 番 10 号
株 式 会 社 Link_Mobile

代表 取締 役 佐々 木 勉

貸借 対照 表 の 要旨 (平成 31 年 3 月 31 日 現在 }
```

```
# tesseract B.png stdout -l jpn --psm 6
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
。 人 加計
区 三 6 番 12 号
中 野 駅 前 ビル 5 | 、
am 人 mw
に て
貸借 対照 表 の 要旨 ( 令 和 元 年 11 月 30 日 現在 }
```

---

Update 1

> Were both scanned using the same scanner, and at the same resolution?

Yes. The images that were originally included in the same PDF were cut out.

> Are you taking advantage of any APIs which Tesseract exposes for pre-processing the images before doing OCR?

No. I did not know that. I am checking now about it.

Comment: Can you tell us more about these two images?  Were both scanned using the same scanner, and at the same resolution?  Are you taking advantage of any APIs which Tesseract exposes for pre-processing the images before doing OCR?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi. "Yes same resolution" and "No, I don't use it". I did not know the API. I am checking now.

Comment: You should be using it.  Some scans won't generate any output unless the image be cleaned up.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Will try it and post the result!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Rescaling image worked on improving!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It improved. I read "[Tesseract documentation](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality)" and rescaled the image.

> Rescaling
>   Tesseract works best on images which have a DPI of at least 300 dpi, so it may be beneficial to resize images. For more information see the FAQ.

- Rescaled image

[image]

- Run OCR

```
# tesseract B2.png stdout -l jpn --psm 6
第 54 期 決 算 公 告 _ 令 和 2 年 1 月 29 日
東京 都 中 野 区 中 野 三 丁目 36 番 12 号
中 野 駅 前 ビル 5 F
株 式 会 社 コ ー エ ー テ クニ カ
代表 取締 役 小 空 _ 修
貸借 対照 表 の 要旨 ( 令 和 元 年 11 月 30 日 現在 )
```